# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.Jdk14RegexpRegexp on Java 11

Tags: java, ant, java-11

I am using ant-nodeps.jar in my Java class to build EAR file by combining plugins.
Getting the following error after migrating to Java 11 from Java 8.

> Caused by: No supported regular expression matcher found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.Jdk14RegexpRegexp
> at org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.RegexpFactory.newRegexp(RegexpFactory.java:92)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.types.RegularExpression.init(RegularExpression.java:80)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.types.RegularExpression.getPattern(RegularExpression.java:110)
> at classpath//org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp.doReplace(ReplaceRegExp.java:347)
> at classpath//org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp.execute(ReplaceRegExp.java:503)
> at classpath//org.app.tools.ant.appReplaceRegExp.replaceregexp(appReplaceRegExp.java:31)
> at classpath//org.app.tools.ant.appReplaceRegExp.replaceregexp(appReplaceRegExp.java:14)
> at org.app.assembler.war.WARAssembler.assembleScriptIncludes(WARAssembler.java:452)
> at org.app.assembler.war.WARAssembler.execute(WARAssembler.java:122)
> ... 35 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.Jdk14RegexpRegexp
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ClasspathUtils.newInstance(ClasspathUtils.java:266)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.RegexpFactory.createRegexpInstance(RegexpFactory.java:107)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.RegexpFactory.newRegexp(RegexpFactory.java:72)
> ... 43 more

I am using ant-1.7.1 version.
Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider upgrading ant version to a more recent one. 1.7.1 dates back to July 2008, so 13 years ago.